# Why isn't my AJAX form working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

I'm learning Rails and am trying to implement AJAX to my sample app. I'm following this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised) and I think I'm doing everything it said, but it isn't working and I can't seem to figure out why.

1. I've got `remote: true`.
2. I have the `respond_to` block where I respond to the `js` format.
3. I render `create.js.erb` if the format is `js`.

The code in `create.js.erb` isn't being executed. I've got a `alert('test');` that isn't appearing. However, if I refresh the page, the new comment is shown. What am I doing wrong?

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for [@article, @comment], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :author, label: 'Name' %>
    <%= f.input :body %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
        @comment.article_id = params[:article_id]
        if @comment.save
            respond_to do |f|
                f.html { redirect_to article_path(params[:article_id]), notice: 'Comment created!' }
                f.js { render 'create.js.erb' }
            end
        else
            redirect_to article_path(params[:article_id]), warning: 'Unable to create comment.'
        end
    end

    private

        def comment_params
            params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :body)
        end
end
```

**create.js.erb**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('test');
    $('#comments').html("<%= j render('comments/list_comments') %>");
});
```

**stack trace**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/articles/2/comments 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:9667
send jquery.js?body=1:9667
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9212
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:81
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:157
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:364
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4625
elemData.handle
```

**updated stack trace** last line is slightly different

```
POST http://localhost:3000/articles/2/comments 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:9667
send jquery.js?body=1:9667
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:9212
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:81
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:157
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:364
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:4625
elemData.handle jquery.js?body=1:4293
```

**Rails console output**

```
Started POST "/articles/2/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-19 17:12:16 -0400
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"author"=>"hhh", "body"=>"hhh"}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "article_id"=>"2"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("article_id", "author", "body", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["article_id", 2], ["author", "hhh"], ["body", "hhh"], ["created_at", Mon, 19 May 2014 21:12:16 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 19 May 2014 21:12:16 UTC +00:00]]
   (31.2ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered comments/_list_comments.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered comments/create.js.erb (2.7ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 56ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <div id="comments">
    2:  <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
    3:      <hr />
    4:      <p><small><%= comment.author %></small></p>
    5:      <p><%= comment.body %></p>
  app/views/comments/_list_comments.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_comments__list_comments_html_erb__1695291160912137125_70349468259020'
  app/views/comments/create.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_comments_create_js_erb___4307677746730482839_70349467492020'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:6:in `create'
```

**_list_comments.html.erb**

```
<div id="comments">
    <% @comments.each do |comment| %>
        <hr />
        <p><small><%= comment.author %></small></p>
        <p><%= comment.body %></p>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: what errors on your command when submit form?

Comment: I've never seen the `$(document).ready(function() { }` bit in a js template before. Maybe take that out?

Comment: In respond_to block do place your `f.js { ...}` before `f.html { redirect_to ...}` line and see.

Comment: @pdobb just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @uDaY just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @anonymousxxx `POST http://localhost:3000/articles/2/comments 500 (Internal Server Error) `

Comment: Can you paste the stacktrace?

Comment: remove `$(document).ready` from `create.js.erb`

Comment: @uDaY I pasted the stacktrace in the question.

Comment: @pawel7318 I did, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @AdamZerner as you show stacktrace it's clear the problem is somewhere else, but.. remove it anyway :)

Comment: Show the stacktrace from console. @Adam

Comment: @uDaY you mean the browser console? I thought that's what I did.

Comment: @AdamZerner no I meant terminal/cmd console, the trace that you get when you run server. look at the point where it throws the error & copy paste that.

Comment: @uDaY ahh ok. I just added it to the question. Sorry about that (I'm a beginner).

Comment: @Adam did you do `rake db migrate` after creating comments model?

Comment: @uDaY yes. The form worked prior to AJAX. And the comments are added after I refresh the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53994/discussion-between-uday-and-adam-zerner).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

on your **comments_controller**:

```
f.js { @comments = Comment.all }
```

on your **create.js.erb**:

```
$("#comments").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'comments/list_comments', :locals => {:comments => @comments}) %>");
```

Comment: Didn't change anything :/

Comment: Error message didnt change?

Comment: See the edit to the question with the console output from the Rails console.

Comment: Whats in your _list_comments.html.erb partial view?

Comment: Glad it helped! Did you understand what happened, right?

Comment: No, I'm actually still thinking about it and am confused. Why didn't `create.js.erb` have access to `@comments`?

Comment: And even if it `create.js.erb` didn't have access to `@comments`, why wasn't `alert('test')` working?

Comment: create.js.erb is related to the method 'create' on your controller. If you want create.js.erb to 'see' @comments, the you need to invoke it in create method

Comment: alert('test) wasnt working because you were creating a JQuery file, inside js.erb, the pattern for doing ajax with rails is the way that I showed

Comment: Oh ok, I just went through the sequence and I understand. I was confusing `@comment` with `@comments`. `@comment` is available because of the form and I was thinking `@comments` was too cuz I was grouping them together.

Comment: I still don't get why `alert('test')` wasn't working though. It works now that I made `@comments` available.